# How to write sql query efficiently in this case?

Tags: sql

I have a table that lists students and their ranks.

Like so,

```
studentName, studentRank
```

Now, in my UI client side, I show a list of all students in a listbox ordered by their rank.

```
[ StudentName, StudentRank]
```

Now a professor in this UI can drag drop and re-order students as he chooses, and then "saves"

When the save happens, I need to get the list from the ListBox and then do an update on the table so that the students are now ranked according to the list in the UI.

To do this, the simplest way I am doing right now, is to delete all previous rows and then insert them one by one by increasing the rank after each insert in the student table.
I feel that this is unnecessary....but am not sure.

I was wondering if there is a better way to achieve this?

Comment: If the size of the table is small enough that it's manageable for your UI, then it's probably manageable to delete/insert all of the items.  Your human users are likely to complain about the UI being unweidly well before they complain about the DB insert afterwards being too slow.

Comment: Do an update: `update students set studentRank = newRankVariable where studentName = 'nameVariable'`

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about minimizing the database changes, you can track which rows have  a rank that has changes and only do updates for those. If this is worthwhile or not depends on the scale of your data and how much, if any, logging you will incur.

For example if you have ten students and swap rank 5 and 6 you minimum update affects only 2 rows whereas your default drop and add required 10 deletes and 10 inserts. If you instead move a student up from rank 8 to rank 5 you have more updates, but still fewer:

```
UPDATE student SET rank = rank + 1 WHERE ranking BETWEEN 5 AND 7
UPDATE student SET rank = 5 WHERE name = @name
```

But figuring the optimal SQL is complicated and likely not worth the effort. Probably best to just update the rows that change.

If you do delete and reinsert you may want to TRUNCATE instead of DELETE. And do it in a transaction to make sure you delete does work and then the insert fail.

Comment: And when professore decided to drop stident rank in more than 1 point what will your example will do then?

Comment: @AllBlond Dropping a student N ranks just moves next N students up 1 rank each. So it's basically the same.

Answer (score -1):

Include in your table field like studentid and then run update by studentid which will be faster then deleting and inserting data all over and over.